# How do I detect a call to Xorg to do screenshots?

Tags: linux, x11, screenshot

X can do screen shots of the entire desktop. I'd like to detect these calls as they're made, but through something like ebpf or sysdig, rather than patching the calls at the server level. How can I do this and is there a program that can do this as well?

Answer (score 4):

[more of a comment than an answer, but too long for a comment]

A program which would do that will have to hook into the X11 calls at server level (via a mechanism like [`XACE`](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xorg-docs/specs/Xserver/XACE-Spec.html), ~ just like ebpf or sysdig do with the calls in the kernel). I don't know of anything ready-made doing that, but then I didn't do too much research on the matter ;-)

If you want to just to monitor the requests performed by an X11 client, you could use the [`RECORD`](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/recordproto/record.html) extension (as [`xtruss`](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/xtruss/) does) or force the client through X11 proxy like [`xscope`](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xscope.1.html) and look for any `CopyArea`, `GetImage`, etc requests using the root window as the source (or any window/pixmap NOT owned by that client).

In general, obsessing about an X11 application being able to do "screenshots" is pretty pointless, since any program with access to an X11 server can do much more, and if not trusted should NOT be left anywhere near it. Also, local processes running under the same user can also `ptrace(2)` each other and read each other's memory directly.

Comment: fwiw, you can set an owned process as non-dumpable to prevent tracing it with `prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE,0,0,0,0)` eg with gdb but without devel/debug environment available, on an amd64 (x86_64) arch: `gdb --batch-silent -ex 'print (int)prctl(4,0,0,0,0)' -ex detach -ex quit  --pid=$(pidof sleep)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i'd rather be more focussed on other things than wondering if an X11 app is screenshotting, but i thought i'd scratch this itch for now.

There doesn't seem to be any material on the how to write these x11 hooks on the web, but i'll look into xtruss.

I'm running xtruss at the moment. Using the X id's i've obtained from xwininfo -root -tree, i'm setting xtruss to monitor that resource. However, when i do a xwd -i  -out file, xtruss does not report anything. Is the testing methodology wrong?

Comment: `xtruss -p ID` does not monitor the resource identified by `ID`, but the _X11 client_ which has created it. `xtruss` can only "catch" new clients by running it in proxy mode, like `xtruss -e GetImage xterm`, where it will also catch an `xwd` started from within `xterm`. Unfortunately `xtruss` is somehow outdated, and doesn't know how to decode the requests and events from many extensions. And just like truss/strace whose interface it mimics, its filtering and formatting capabilities are very limited.